# Форма 2 вылетает при старте программы

Tags: delphi, форма

Код следующий:

```
procedure TForm1.PerestanovkaButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Sum:Int64;
  index:Integer;
  n, i:Integer;
begin
if (VvodPerestanovkaEdit.Text ='') then i:=Form2.ShowModal else
n:=StrToInt(VvodPerestanovkaEdit.Text);
Sum:=1;
for index:=1 to n do
Sum:=Sum*index;
VyvodPerestanovkaEdit.Text:=IntToStr(Sum);
end;
```

Проблема в том, что 2 форма вылетает не при нажатии на кнопку PerestanovkaButton, а при старте программы. Никаких ошибок программой не обнаружено.

Прошу помочь. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Почитайте об [автосоздаваемых формах](http://www.delphi-manual.ru/lesson8.php). А также посмотрите, там в OnCreate ничего лишнего нет случайно?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Я перевёл 2 форму из разряда автосоздаваемых, но при нажатии на кнопку расчёта вместо 2 формы вылетает следующая ошибка:
[Warning] Unit1.pas(99): Variable 'n' might not have been initialized, что переводится дословно как "Переменная -н , возможно, не был инициализирован".

Comment: Почитайте об автосоздаваемых формах. А также посмотрите, там в OnCreate ничего лишнего нет случайно?

Прочёл. В OnCreate 1 формы ничего нет. Добавил проверку создания формы как указано в теме автосоздаваемых форм. Проблема осталась та же.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, я разобрался. На будущее, если у кого появится подобная проблема выложу код:

```
procedure TForm1.PerestanovkaButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Sum:Int64;
  index:Integer;
  n:Integer;
begin
if (not Assigned(Form2)) then
Form2:=TForm2.Create(Self) else
if (VvodPerestanovkaEdit.Text ='') then i:=Form2.ShowModal else
n:=StrToInt(VvodPerestanovkaEdit.Text);
Sum:=1;
for index:=1 to n do
Sum:=Sum*index;
VyvodPerestanovkaEdit.Text:=IntToStr(Sum);
end;
```

Чтобы знали, так сказать.

Answer (score 0):

В случае, если у Вас `if (VvodPerestanovkaEdit.Text ='')` переменная n буден не инициализирована и теоретически может иметь любое значение (хотя дельфи обычно нулит его)

Comment: Пробовал присваивать значению n ноль и единицу. Однако вылетает ошибка [Hint] Unit1.pas(102): Value assigned to 'n' never used (присваиваемое значение 'n' никогда не использовалось). И в коде выделяется строка коричневым цветом со следующим текстом Form2.ShowModal = Inaccessible value (Форма 2 модальная = недоступное значение). Перестала она быть доступной после того как я перенёс её из списка автосоздаваемых в список доступных форм.

Comment: Открою секрет - Hint это просто подсказка компилятора :-)

Comment: И да, если вы форму не автосоздаёте - Вам надо эту форму самому где то создать до первого использования. Например перед вызовом ShowModal сделать `From2 := TForm2.Create(...)`

Comment: i - глобальная переменная типа integer. Я её туда перенёс.

Comment: Код:
procedure TForm1.RazmeschenieButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Sum1, Sum2:Int64;
  index, n, k, A, b:Integer;
begin
if (not Assigned(Form2)) then Form2:=TForm2.Create(Self) else
if (VvodNRazmeschenieEdit.Text ='') then i:=Form2.ShowModal else
if (VvodKRazmeschenieEdit.Text ='') then i:=Form2.ShowModal else
n:=StrToInt(VvodNRazmeschenieEdit.Text);
k:=StrToInt(VvodKRazmeschenieEdit.Text);
Sum1:=1;
for index:=1 to n do
Sum1:=Sum1*index;
b:=n-k;
Sum2:=1;
for index:=1 to b do
begin
Sum2:=Sum2*index;
end;
A:=Round(Sum1/Sum2);
VyvodRazmeschenieEdit.Text:=IntToStr(A);
end;

Comment: Вопрос по этой же теме. Я перенёс это решение в другую часть кода, и получил после компиляции при нажатии кнопки следующие ошибки:
[Warning] Unit1.pas(101): Variable 'n' might not have been initialized
[Warning] Unit1.pas(190): Variable 'n' might not have been initialized
Программа та же, потому форма 2 перенесена в разряд доступных.